# formaction attribute and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have HTML form and two submit buttons. One of them has `formaction` attribute.

```
<form action="Action1" method="POST" id="myForm">
    <input type="text" name="field1">
    <input type="text" name="field2">
    <button type="submit">Search</button>
    <button type="submit" formaction="Action2">Save search defaults</button>
</form>
```

Then, I have the following Javascript code:

```
$('#myForm').on('submit', function () {
    var form = $(this);
    var url = form.attr('action');

    console.log(url);
});
```

Why is `url` always equal to `Action1`, even if I click on button with `formaction="Action2"`? How can I get correct form action when I click on second button?

Comment: Because $(this) will always point to the <form> tag whose action attribute is "Action1"

Answer (score 1):

As already pointed out, `$(this).attr('action')` always refers to the `action` attribute of your form itself, since that's the element your event is defined on.

What you can do itself is check for the `formaction` of [`document.activeElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentOrShadowRoot/activeElement), which gives you the element that is currently focused. If it's not defined, you then fall back to the form action itself.

**Demo:**

```js
$('#myForm').on('submit', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var url = $(document.activeElement).attr('formaction') || $(this).attr('action');

  console.log(url);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="Action1" method="POST" id="myForm">
  <input type="text" name="field1">
  <input type="text" name="field2">
  <button type="submit">Search</button>
  <button type="submit" formaction="Action2">Save search defaults</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you're listening to the form submission - therefore `$(this)` in your code makes `form` the `<form>` element. You can listen for the submit button click instead:

```
$("[type='submit']").on("click", function() {
    var url = $(this).attr("formaction");
    console.log(url);
});
```